# how to give admin approval to authors' posts before publish them

Tags: blogger

I have a blog in www.blogger.com. some authors publish their articles on this blog. sometimes they publish unwanted content on this blog. So, it's better to use admin approval before publish articles.i tried to solve this,but I can't find solution for this yet.
please tell me how to give admin approval to authors' posts before publish them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, something like this is not possible. If a user is an Author, then they can create posts without any kind of approvals from Admin. A work around for this is to use the `Posting using email` feature available under Settings > Email and set the option to `Save emails as draft post` This way users can only email in the new posts and they need to be approved by the Admin before being published.